# How do I perform bit operations in glsl

Tags: glsl, bitwise-operators

How do I perform bit operations in glsl?

Using the regular C style bitwise operators `|`, `&`, `^`, or `!` does not work.

Comment: See example code here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23730491/763355

Answer (score 9):

They have been introduced with GLSL 1.30 (OGL 3.0).

Depending on what you want to do, you could eventually emulate them with floating point operations, `x & (2^n)-1 = frac(x/(2^n))*(2^n)` for example, but you'll have to take care of floating point errors.

Comment: Are there more examples like that?  This AND operation is what I needed the most, but also some OR would come in handy...

Comment: @St0fF If you can find a way to do `¬` (not gate) then you can combine it with `∧` (and gate) using DeMorgan's law to obtain `p ∨ q = ¬( ¬p ∧ ¬q )`.

Answer (score 9):

You need to put either

```
#version 130
```

or

```
#extension GL_EXT_gpu_shader4 : enable
```

in the top of your shader to get access to the bit operators